# Como realizar una consulta que devuelva la diferencia entre dos marcas de tiempo o fechas?

Tags: php, mysql

Rapidamente dare una explicacion de lo que estoy haciendo, tengo una clase `php` que se encarga de enviar codigo de seguridad al correo electronico que lo esta solicitando para autorizar el cambio de constraseña, luego tengo otra clase que se encarga de validar si el codigo que se ingreso es valido o no, dentro de esta clase php tengo una funcion en particular que se encarga de validar si el codigo ingresado aun esta vigente, es decir, se encarga de verificar si el codigo excedio o no los 60 min desde su solicitud, en caso de que haya superado los 60 min se elimina:

```
private function actualizarCodigos(){
            /**
             * EN ESTA FUNCION LO QUE SE HACE ES ELIMINAR LOS CODIGOS QUE EXPIRARON LOS 60MIN(1 HORA).
             */
            try {
                $this->clase_dbconexion = new dbconexion();
                $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->conectar();
                $consulta = $conexion->prepare("DELETE FROM codigo_seguridad WHERE DATE_ADD(fecha_creacion, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) < NOW()");
                $consulta->execute();
                $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->desconectar($conexion);
                return true;

            } catch (PDOException $exception) {
                //echo('Se produjo un error al actualizar codigos expirados: ' . $exception->getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Lo que ahora quiero hacer es de que si el codigo aun esta vigente que me devuelva cuanto tiempo me queda de vigencia y asi puede avisarle al cliente que aun su codigo esta vigente y que le queda un determinado tiempo de vigencia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una vez que ejecutemos la query de eliminar, los registros restantes deberían ser aquellos que aún son válidos, por lo que podemos seleccionarlos todos sin complicarnos en la construcción del WHERE.

En cuanto a la expresión para sacar el tiempo faltante, podemos usar TIMESTAMPDIFF de la siguiente manera:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), DATE_ADD(tiempo, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE))
```

En este caso obtenemos la diferencia de tiempo en minutos entre el momento actual y el minuto en que expira el código.

Obtener este valor para todos los códigos guardados sería algo así:

```
SELECT *Otros campos que queramos obtener*, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), DATE_ADD(fecha_creacion, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE))
FROM codigo_seguridad;
```

Edición:

Para dar formato al resultado basta con combinar la función CONCAT() con las operaciones básicas. Por ejemplo, si el campo *Columna* valiese 'VALOR', usar lo siguiente:

```
CONCAT('texto anterior ', Columna, ' texto siguiente')
```

Resultaría en algo así: 'texto anterior VALOR texto siguiente'

Por otro lado, podemos obtener horas minutos y segundos con operaciones sencillas como divisiones enteras y módulo.

Por ejemplo, las horas se obtienen dividiendo los segundos totales entre los segundos que tiene una hora de la siguiente manera:

```
SegundosTotales DIV 3600
```

DIV corresponde a la división entera, la cual descarta los decimales que resulten de la división.

Hasta ahora suena fácil, pero hay que recordar que "SegundosTotales" no es un campo que exista actualmente, sino que es el resultado de la siguiente operación (La cual es muy larga):

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), DATE_ADD(tiempo, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE))
```

A partir de aquí se empieza a ver problemático el asunto, pues por cada campo tendremos que hacer operaciones con el resultado de la operación antes mencionada, lo cual resultará en una sentencia extremadamente grande y complicada.

En honor a la sanidad mental, será mejor que creemos una vista que le asigne un nombre a toda la expresión anterior, de manera que usemos dicho nombre al hacer cálculos.

Crear una vista sería algo así:

```
CREATE VIEW tiempo_restante AS
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), DATE_ADD(fecha_creacion, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)) as SegundosTotales
FROM codigo_seguridad;
```

(Deberíamos aprovechar la vista y obtener más campos de la tabla original con ella, pero no se como se llamen los demás campos de tu tabla así que por el momento solo se toma en cuenta *fecha_creacion*)

Con dicha vista como auxiliar, ya podemos hacer selecciones en múltiples formatos sin mucha dificultad, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT SegundosTotales DIV 3600 AS Horas,
(SegundosTotales % 3600) DIV 60 AS Minutos,
SegundosTotales % 60 AS Segundos,
CONCAT(
    SegundosTotales DIV 3600,
    ':',
    (SegundosTotales % 3600) DIV 60,
    ':',
    SegundosTotales % 60
) as HoraConFormato
FROM tiempo_restante;
```

Comment: funciona, pero me devuelve en minutos, como hago para que me devuelva en un formato `HH:mm:ss`,  se que la hora no es necesario pero quisiera mantener la formalidad.

Comment: @Leonidas Bueno eso ya es jugar con el formato devuelto. Dejame editar la respuesta para incluirlo.